# Help proving that $ A \times B \subset \mathcal P(\mathcal P(A \cup B))$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Help in order to prove the following statement:
$$ A \times B \subset \mathcal P(\mathcal P(A \cup B))$$ where $P(A)$ means the power set of $A$

I need to prove that for any $(x,y) \in A \times B$ then $(x,y) \in \mathcal P(\mathcal P(A \cup B))$ but this means prove that $(x,y) \subset \mathcal P(A \cup B)$ so I need to take an element in $(x,y)$ to prove this , so I'm confused because of this last step. Any help in order to end proving this statement will be apreciated. Thanks

Comment: What is $P$? Is it the projection of something? The power set?

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг P being the power set is very standard notation, especially given the context and original tags....

Comment: $P$ means the power set

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$$(a,b)=\{\{a\},\{a,b\}\}$$

by definition.

Comment: The [Kuratowshi definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_pair#Kuratowski_definition) anyway.

Answer (score 0):

$$A\times B=\{\mathcal{X}\in\mathscr{P}(\mathscr{P}(A\cup B)):(\exists a\in A)(\exists b\in B)[\mathcal{X}=(a,b)]\}$$ where
$$(a,b):= \{\{a\},\{a,b\}\}. $$